# Invoke each Function in array of Classes

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

If i had numerous `Person` Objects stored in an `array`, how would i invoke the same function for each object.

```
  class Person 
    constructor: (_age) ->
      @age = _age

    addAge: (_num) ->
      @age = @age + _num



  _peeps = [new Person(5),new Person(9),new Person(50)]

  _peeps.addAge(2)
```

Im looking for something better than multiple `for` loops or alike , as ideally there be would numerous `Person` Objects with even more methods.

Is there a workaround for this ?

Thanks, Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
result = _peeps.map (o) -> return o.addAge(2)
```

Or:

```
_peeps.forEach (o) -> o.addAge(2)
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/7e0L1hpq/